# Fetching the results of a SQL query into a hash map in PERL

Tags: perl, hash, iteration

I am a beginner to perl. So am just trying out some random perl codes.
I have an sql query which gives me a number of rows, with 2 values in each row.
I want to store this result into a hash say

```
%result_hash
```

in such a way that the first value will be the key and second one will be its value.

I tried it with a while-loop which iterates over each row. Its working fine.
I wanted to know if there is any other simpler way of doing this..

Comment: Please show us your existing code.

Comment: Your question is quite obscure without any hint of perl code or database used. It is not clear if you fetch SQL result into array or into hash. Did you look for example at DBI for mysql/mariadb? Did you research **fetchrow_array** and **fetchrow_hashref** see [webpage](https://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/perl/dbd_odbc_tutorial_part_2.html). There are so many free databases and which one you refer is unclear: mySQL/mariadb,postgreSQL,SQlite,DBM, ...

Comment: Please look into [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) also into [quick start](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_perl.htm) for [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html) .

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to help without knowing what mechanisms you're using to access the database. For future reference, please include the relevant pieces of your code in your questions.

But you should be using [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI). And if you are, then that library has a [`fetchrow_hashref()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchrow_hashref) method that returns each row in the result set as a hash reference. The keys in the hash are the column names and the values are the column values.

**Update:** As Grinnz points out below, it's possible that [`selectall_hashref()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#selectall_hashref) is closer to what you want. It's hard to be sure though.

Comment: `selectall_hashref` would be closer to what the OP asked for (if I understand correctly), as it would return a hash keyed by the value of a certain column. But each value would be the row as a hash, not a single value. I've often wished for a `selectall_hashref` alternative that can specify the values to be a single column value as well.